# How to use tfrxMemoView of fastReport as a New VCL Component?

Tags: components, fastreport

I must figure out that how can i create a component exactly as tfrxMemoView from fastReport with all properties except the database related ones?

Is there any solution to create an inherited component from tfrxMemoView or any similar component does exists?

Answer (score 0):

See FR Developer's manual "Writing Custom Report Components" chapter

Also you can inherite your new component from TfrxMemoView and hide some properties like frxHideProperties(TfrxView, 'DataSetName;BrushStyle;URL');

```
uses frxDsgnIntf;

TfrxMemoView1 = class(TfrxCustomMemoView)
  published
    property AutoWidth;
    property AllowExpressions;
    property AllowHTMLTags;
    property BrushStyle;
    property CharSpacing;
    property Clipped;
    property Color;
    //property DataField;
    //property DataSet;
    property DataSetName;
    property DisplayFormat;
    property ExpressionDelimiters;
    property FlowTo;
    property Font;
    property Frame;
    property FillType;
    property Fill;
    property GapX;
    property GapY;
    property HAlign;
    property HideZeros;
    property Highlight;
    property LineSpacing;
    property Memo;
    property ParagraphGap;
    property ParentFont;
    property Rotation;
    property RTLReading;
    property Style;
    property SuppressRepeated;
    property Underlines;
    property UseDefaultCharset;
    property WordBreak;
    property WordWrap;
    property Wysiwyg;
    property VAlign;
  end;

initialization

frxObjects.RegisterObject1(TfrxMemoView1, nil, '', '', 0, 2, [ctReport, ctData]);
```

Comment: thanks for your replay. but im wondering how can i inherite a new component from tfrxMemoView? can you give me a small sample of that code? i couldnt figure it out by myself. Thank you sir.

Comment: I couldnt figure it out how to use the resulting component like a label! its just a non-visible component.

Comment: thank you, ive done that but still no visual component.. its like the timer component! what about that?